# iOS BLE background execution time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using BLE connection and app needs to run in background forever. For now background mode working, but limited, after few hours system kills app without any notifications and appDelegate methods calls. I checked ram usage, and it not depend, system kills app when ram usage 60mb, and when 200mb. Also app periodically sent POST requests to server(every minute) and using location services. How to extend execution time? Is it possible to run app forever(if user not using other apps)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, iOS is doing dark magic to optimise resources usage and we can't do anything about it.